# how to generate a stack trace from a core dump file in C, without invoking an external tool such as gdb

Tags: linux, stack-trace, coredump

I am looking for a simple way to pull the stack trace out of a Linux core dump file programmatically, without having to invoke gdb. Anybody has an idea?

To avoid confusion: I am *not* looking for a way to get my own back trace from inside a process. I am looking for a way to get a backtrace out of a completely independent core dump file I have.

Comment: I think your best way will be to invoke `gdb`, in batch mode which is easily scriptable if need be.  It's a little hard to ignore the most obvious solution when you don't specify why you refuse to use it...

Comment: Well, the intention here is to have something that can deployed in an embedded environment where we cannot store the coredump, and have no space for gdb, but still want to record the stacktrace for all crashes that happen, as good as possible.

Comment: Then you might want to consider printing the backtrace in your program, before it crashes.  You can install a signal handler for `SIGSEGV` and friends, and then use [backtrace()](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Backtraces.html) and related calls to print out the stack trace, then continue to exit/crash as desired...

Comment: well, it's quite a few programs, and we'd rather avoid having to patch them all (in particular since some of them come in binary form). So we want something that generates the stack traces of all core dumps generated, regardless which process it is

Comment: I don't know of any tools that can do it besides `gdb`, though that doesn't mean you won't find one somehow.  Digging out the parts of gdb that align the core dump with the symbols in the executable (and shared libraries) and do the backtrace doesn't sound like fun, but I suppose it can be done...  good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you really can't invoke gdb, but want a backtrace like the ones it provides, you could just copy the bits of gdb's source that are needed for that into your project.  Obviously just invoking gdb will be easier, more maintainable, and less eyebrow-raising, so maybe you should just do that.